# When I reply to .Prompts.choice() with Direct Line API, my bot doesn't work correctly

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

I'm making a website with Direct Line API.
http://qavppy-bot-test-123.azurewebsites.net/

But, my bot does't recognize messages, when I replay to question of .Promts.choice().
I don't know why, but bot says message of .onDefault().
It seems that bot doesn't work correctly...

When I use another ways(Slack, WebChat, etc),
bot works correctly.

Plz advices.

[Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWLAt.jpg)

Comment: Were you able to solve this? Stuck at the same place as you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the 'from' property in the request was not set.

Try setting the 'from' property and Prompt.Choice should work.